# Code chunk using repmis::dropboxData works in one Rstudio project but not another

Tags: r, rstudio, reproducible-research

I have two R projects associated with github repositories.
I have been using the repmis function source_DropboxData to download a file, then tbl_df in dplyr

In both projects the code is:

```
require(repmis)
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2)


# simd vars

simd_2009 <- source_DropboxData(
    file="simd_2009.csv",
    key="ghiu8n9db6rch9y"    
    ) %>% tbl_df()
```

In one of the projects this crashes RStudio; in the other it does not.

sessionInfo() on the project that works:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.9     ggplot2_1.0.0 tidyr_0.2.0   dplyr_0.4.1   plyr_1.8.1    repmis_0.3.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1    colorspace_1.2-4  DBI_0.3.1         digest_0.6.8      evaluate_0.5.5    formatR_1.0       grid_3.1.2       
 [8] gtable_0.1.2      httr_0.6.1        magrittr_1.5      MASS_7.3-35       munsell_0.4.2     packrat_0.4.2-1   parallel_3.1.2   
[15] proto_0.3-10      R.cache_0.10.0    R.methodsS3_1.6.1 R.oo_1.18.0       R.utils_1.34.0    Rcpp_0.11.3       reshape2_1.4.1   
[22] rJava_0.9-6       scales_0.2.4      stringr_0.6.2     tools_3.1.2       xlsx_0.5.7        xlsxjars_0.6.1
```

sessionInfo() on the project that crashes:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0 tidyr_0.2.0   dplyr_0.4.1   plyr_1.8.1    repmis_0.4   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1    chron_2.3-45      colorspace_1.2-4  data.table_1.9.4  DBI_0.3.1         digest_0.6.4      grid_3.1.2       
 [8] gtable_0.1.2      httr_0.6.1        magrittr_1.5      MASS_7.3-35       munsell_0.4.2     packrat_0.4.2-1   parallel_3.1.2   
[15] proto_0.3-10      R.cache_0.10.0    R.methodsS3_1.6.1 R.oo_1.18.0       R.utils_1.34.0    Rcpp_0.11.3       reshape2_1.4     
[22] rJava_0.9-6       scales_0.2.4      stringr_0.6.2     tools_3.1.2       xlsx_0.5.7        xlsxjars_0.6.1
```

What is likely to be the cause of the difference and how could I investigate further?

## Update

Clearly the main difference is that the version that works uses repmis_0.3.3 and the version that doesn't uses repmis_0.4. I'm going to look at using repmis to downgrade itself!

The downgrade did not seem to work - "installation had non-zero exit status"

n.b. I'm also using `packrat` on both projects

- I've now tried repmis 0.4 outside of either package, it works. However plyr and dplyr are not installed.
- It works with plyr installed...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `packrat` was causing the issue. Removing it solved the problem!

Comment: If this is reproducible, could you file an issue for packrat? https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues

Comment: Great suggestion - The configuration that crashes is on github so I should be doable. Thanks